# Can I use test token in Stripe Connect to create test charge?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

My PHP application is using Stripe. People sell their products on my platform and I'm getting my fee from it. I already have a link that makes it possible for users to connect their Stripe accounts to my platform. I get authentication code and then I use it to get access token. The response is as follows (replaced long random strings with abcd):

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "stripe_publishable_key": "pk_test_abcd",
  "scope": "read_write",
  "livemode": false,
  "stripe_user_id": "acct_abcd",
  "refresh_token": "rt_abcd",
  "access_token": "sk_test_abcd"
}
```

Then, I'm trying to create a test charge for a connected account:

```
$charge = Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount'   => 1000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'source'   => 'sk_test_abcd',
], ['stripe_account' => 'acct_abcd']);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> No such token: sk_test_abcd

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When [creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge), the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter should be set to a card [token](https://stripe.com/docs/api#token_object) ID. In your example, you're using the destination account's API key, which is a different concept altogether. You need to use either the `source` parameter with a card token returned by [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js), or the `customer` parameter with the ID of a customer object that you created previously.

As a side note, you don't need to worry about the API keys you get in the [response](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#post-token-response) in the last step of the Connect OAuth flow. The only field of interest is the `stripe_user_id` field containing the account's ID. You should save this ID in your database, so you can then use it with the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header to issue API requests on behalf of this account.

Comment: Are you sure it must be a card's token? Stripe's OAuth documentation is not very clear about it: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees - how can I send money to a person without knowing their cards? I just want to send money to their Stripe account.

Comment: Stripe cannot be used as a money transmission service or as an e-wallet. The purpose of Stripe Connect is to allow platforms to accept charges on behalf of other accounts. So you can't just send money from your Stripe account to another account -- you would need to create a charge from an actual card, and that charge would have to be for a good or service provided by the connected account's owner.

Comment: @Ywain  can i send the money to my stripe connected accounts if not can you please suggest an alternative way for that using stripe.